# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget & java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, bitmapimage, ioerror

I have taken over some one else's project as they have left now, however because it isn't my code and i'm not experienced in java i keep getting various errors on my application.

The first error that i am recieving is as follows:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   http://images.ultrait.me/ImageProcessor.aspx?imageURL=381/Sales/321466/58441_T_ADDRESSES_57075_OT.jpg&Text=LET_AGREED

As you can see from clicking the link the message appears, this is reading this information from a feed(which i do not have access too). However it will not display on the application for some unknown reason. (I would also like to point out the feed and images are working fine on the iPhone application)

The second error i am recieving is as follows:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

here is the code that the project is saying that it is erroring on :

```
 bm_images = new Bitmap[10];
        for(int i=0; i<10;++i)
            bm_images[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.downloading);
```

I have a simular application that already does what i want my current application to do and the code is practically similar. So i really have no ideas as i have been comparing both versions against one another.

As i say i am not a java pro and i really am unsure of what is causing this, if any one needs any other information to maybe try and help i don't mind sending information, i would be grateful for any help that any one can give me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Be remember that, each and everytime when your Bitmap did its work then make it null and recycle like ***mBitmap=null*** and ***mBitmap.recycle()***. It will clear your Bitmap and application will release that much memory, so your app will not throw an Exception.

Comment: i recommend doing it in opposite dirrection :P